# How to set default font feature settings?

Tags: css, fonts, opentype

## How to set default font feature settings per font?

I am using two different fonts in my current project and want to enable font-feature-settings on both of them.
Currently I have to do this via the `*` selector:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum" "ss01";
     -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum" "ss01";
      -ms-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum" "ss01";
          font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum" "ss01";
}
```

So far so good; this way I set kerning, ligatures and proportional numbers as a default. The problem is the alternative stylistic set.
I want to have this one on every instance of **one** of my fonts. The other font has another stylistic set, which I do not want to use.

My prefered way would be to incorporate defaults in the `@font-face` like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FFDin';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum" "ss01";
     -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum" "ss01";
      -ms-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum" "ss01";
          font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum" "ss01";

  src: url("fonts/DINWeb-Light.eot");
  src: url("fonts/DINWeb-Light.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("fonts/DINWeb-Light.woff") format("woff"),
       url("fonts/DINWeb-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

I have tested this in chrome, but it does not work. Is there any way to declare the default font-feature settings per font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s possible the way you have tried, but Chrome and IE don’t support it; Firefox does.

CSS Fonts Module Level 3 is somewhat obscure, as it does not contain a formal description of what is allowed inside `@font-face`, but since section 4 [Font Resources](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-resources) seems to be meant to describe 
`@font-face` and it defined `font-feature-settings` as a descriptor, your approach should work. It also described in [MDN info on `@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face). However, the W3C CSS validator rejects it, perhaps due to the obscurity of the spec (Candidate Recommendation).

I tested this using the Google font Source Sans Pro and the `ordn` feature. Though the following code does not run unless you have Source Sans Pro suitably installed locally, it ullustrates the approach in a simpler setting:

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix')  
      format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ordn";
       -moz-font-feature-settings: "ordn";
         -o-font-feature-settings: "ordn";
            font-feature-settings: "ordn";   
}
.no-ordn {
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ordn" 0;
       -moz-font-feature-settings: "ordn" 0;
         -o-font-feature-settings: "ordn" 0;
            font-feature-settings: "ordn" 0;   
}
.ordn {
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ordn";
       -moz-font-feature-settings: "ordn";
         -o-font-feature-settings: "ordn";
            font-feature-settings: "ordn";   
}
p {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
}

</style>
<p>1st 2nd 3rd 4th
<p class=no-ordn>1st 2nd 3rd 4th
<p class=ordn>1st 2nd 3rd 4th
```

The first paragraph should shot 1st 2nd 4th with the letters as superscript glyphs, and this is what happens in Firefox. The second paragraph is just for testing that a font feature set on a font can be overridden in normal CSS for some elements. The third paragraph is for testing that the browser supports font features at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "obscurity of the spec"? 
I would agree with your interpretation. And a bit more clearly: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-fonts/#font-rend-desc describes for font-feature-settings that "These descriptors define initial settings that apply when the font defined by an @font-face rule is rendered.".

Comment: @Abrax5, I’m referring to lack of explicit syntax definition for a `@font-face` rule. The syntax given says that it contains “descriptor declarations”, which are of the form *property*: *expression*, but it does not say what properties may appear there. The intent is apparently that the properties listed in section 4 may appear, but not other CSS properties.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear. I have tried to search the spec for the correct implementation but failed to find it. “Obscurity of the spec” is a fitting description. I hope this will be implemented across all browsers in the near future. That would make a lot of things easier …

Comment: Please be aware that there has never been support for [`-o-font-feature-settings` in Presto](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.12/css/fonts/). By switching to Blink Opera 15 started supporting `-webkit-font-feature-settings`.

Comment: For others that might want to track adoption, here's the Can I Use page: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_font-face_font-feature-settings